# How to understand a Hamiltonian of the form $c^\dagger \sigma^x c$?

Tags: hamiltonian, notation, second-quantization, lattice-model, spin-models

In a 2-dimensional lattice Dirac model (a discretized Hamiltonian on a lattice, the model could be found in this [dissertation](http://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/TI_primer.pdf), equation (2.19)), I found a Hamiltonian with terms like:
$$ H = \sum_{m,n} i c^\dagger_{m+1,n} \sigma^x c_{m,n} - ic^\dagger_{m,n} \sigma^x c_{m+1,n} + \text{etc.}$$

where it is indicated that

> $c_{m,n}=(c_{u,m,n},c_{v,m,n})$ for two degrees of freedom $u,v$.

I am wondering how the creation and annihilation operator "act" with the middle $\sigma^x$ matrix. I know that for a Dirac equation in $(2+1)$-$d$, the wavefunction should have two components. But if I interpret the $c_{m,n}$ as vectors, then the row vector $c^\dagger_{m,n}$ times the $\sigma^x$ and times the column vector $c_{m,n}$ would make the Hamiltonian $H$ a $1\times 1$ matrix. I am stuck here because a $1$x$1$ matrix certainly cannot act on a $2$x$1$ wavefunction.

I realize (through Google) that perhaps I would understand this if I have learned the "quantization of Dirac field", but going from p.1 to p.50 of Peskin's textbook seems to daunting for me. I just want to do some numerical simulation. Could some explain it in a few words?

Update 1: Specifically, by a two component wavefunction, I mean a state like $|\psi\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} \psi_u c^\dagger |0\rangle \\ \psi_v c^\dagger |0\rangle \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Your first thought about treating $c_{mn}$ as vector is probably correct, but it is difficult to answer this without the full context where you found this equation. There are a lot of Hamiltonians that look like the one you have written down depending on how the author has defined things. In a condensed matter context any Hamiltonian with linear dispersion near the Fermi level might be described as "Dirac-like" or a Dirac Hamiltonian, so this doesn't narrow things down as much as you might think.

Comment: @BySymmetry Hi, I have updated a link to the original literature. The authors is considering a square lattice with two fermion degrees of freedom on each  lattice site.

Comment: Having given the source a skim, yes you should treat the action of $\sigma^x$ as you first thought. While this may look like it is 1 dimensional, each term in the Hamiltonian only acts on a different component of the states. Effectively it is writing a matrix as $a_{11}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)+a_{12}\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right) +\dots$

Comment: @BySymmetry And effectively the $u,v$ becomes just one more label like $m,n$. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, exactly. $u$ and $v$ are just indexing your components

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v5): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1):

The usual prescription for transiting to second quantized from is
$$
\hat{\psi}(x)=\sum_\sigma \hat{\psi}_\sigma(x)=\sum_{n,\sigma}\phi_{n,\sigma}c_{n,\sigma},
$$
so that an arbitrary one-particle operator is written as
$$
\hat{\mathcal{A}}= \int dx\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x) \hat {A}\hat{\psi}(x)=
\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}\int dx\hat{\psi}^\dagger_\sigma(x) \hat {A}_{\sigma,\sigma'}\hat{\psi}_{\sigma'}=
\sum_{n,\sigma}\sum_{n',\sigma'}c_{n,\sigma}^\dagger A_{n\sigma,m\sigma'}c_{n',\sigma'}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}c_{n,\uparrow}^\dagger & c_{n,\downarrow}^\dagger\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}A_{n\uparrow,m\uparrow}&A_{n\uparrow,m\downarrow}\\
A_{n\downarrow,m\uparrow}&A_{n\downarrow,m\downarrow}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}c_{m,\uparrow}\\c_{m,\downarrow}^\dagger\end{pmatrix}=
\sum_{n,m}c_n^\dagger A_{n,m}c_m
$$
In other words, we are talking here about usual matrix product - operator in spin space is not acting on the eigenvectors in the Fock space. This is simply an abbreviated notation in space, which is a direct product of space with indices $n,m$ and the spin space.

Answer (score 0):

For the calculation $c^{\dagger}_{m+1,n}\sigma^x c_{m,n} $ we get $c^{\dagger}_{u,m+1,n}c_{v,m,n} +c^{\dagger}_{v,m+1,n}c_{u,m,n} $ .If $(m,n)$ label sites on a lattice then this is not a $1 \times 1$ matrix it is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. To see this, note that these are raising and lowering operators(although they are grassmann variables) and so they need a two dimensional vector space. They need to two states to either lower to or raise to.

Comment: But if we label $c^\dagger |0>$ as $|1>$, then the wavefunction is still one component.

Comment: I believe I didn't make my meaning clear, so I have updated my question.

Comment: @taper $|0>$ is two a dimensional vector, which makes $c^{\dagger}$ a 2 dimensional matrix.